# Static cast in a template

Tags: c++

I have a template with this static cast operator:

```
operator Vector2<float>() const
{
    return Vector2<float>(x, y);
}
```

This implies to me that if I cast as a float, it will return a float variant of the class, even if `x` and `y` are integers from an integer variant. But apparently not so:

As a test:

```
Vector2<float>position=static_cast<float>(Vector2<int>(5,5));
```

I get the compiler error for *No matching conversion for static_cast from Vector2 to float*.

Yet, the conversion is specified above, is it not, as a static cast overload?

Comment: I don't see a `operator float() const` anywhere.

Comment: This implies if you want to cast your object to a `Vector2<float>` you can. Cast direct to `float` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: That implicit conversion is pretty evil. At least make it a named operation. When one doesn't understand what's going on, asking for things to be done silently behind the scenes is really not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
Vector2<float> position = static_cast<Vector2<float>>(Vector2<int>(5,5));
```

since the declaration specified a conversion to `Vector2<float>`, not a conversion to `float`.

Comment: ah thank you, it was a typo in my code that my eyes kept glossing over. much appreciated